# Microservice - Produce And Consume From Same Queue

Tags: asynchronous, architecture, rabbitmq

We are designing a new system, which will be based on microservices. 
I would like to consult, whether it is considered an anti-pattern to produce and consume from the same queue. 
The service should be a REST-based microservice. 
The backend microservice should handle large-scale operations on IoT devices, which may not always be connected to the internet, the API must be asynchronous and provide robust features such as the number of X retries before final failure, etc. 
The API should immediately return a UUID with 201 responses from the POST request and expose 'Get Current Status' (pending, active, done.. etc.) of the operation status of the IoT device, by accepting the UUID in the get request. 
We've thought about two solutions (described at a high level) for managing this task:

1. Implement both API GW Microservice and the logic handler Microservice.
   The API GW will expose the REST API methods and will publish messages via RabbitMQ that will be consumed by multiple instances of the logic handler microservice.
   The main drawback is that we will need to manage multiple deployments, and keep consistency between the APIs exposed in service A, to the consumer in service B.
2. Implement one microservice, that exposes the relevant APIs, and in order to handle the scale and the asynchronous operations, will publish the request to own queue over RabbitMQ, being consumed by the same microservice at a background worker.

The second solution looks easier to develop, maintain, and update because all the logic including the REST API's handling will take care of the same microservice. 
To some members of the team, this solution looks a bit dirty, and we can't decide whether it is an anti-pattern to consume messages of your own queue.

Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: The queue is not the right abstraction for such a system. Look at an orchestrator like temporal.io that encapsulates both state management and queueing.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to consult, whether it is considered an anti-pattern to produce and consume from the same queue.

That definitely sounds suspicious, not that I have a lot of experience with queues.  **But**, you also talk about microservices and "producing" & consuming from those - that sounds fine, there's no reason why a microservice (and by extension, it's API) can't do both.  But then I'm a bit confused because in reading the rest of the question I don't really see how that issue is a factor.

Having some kind of separation between the API and the microservice sounds wise, because you can change the microservices implementation without affecting callers, assuming it's a non-breaking change.  It means you have the ability to solve API / consumer problems, and backend problems, separately.

Version control is just a part of good engineering practice, and probably not an ideal reason to bend your architecture.  You should be able to run more than one version in parallel - a lot of API providers operate a N+2 model, where they support the current version, plus the last two (major) releases.  That way you give your consumers a reasonable runway for upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you keep the two concerns modular so you'd be able to separate them when it would make sense it doesn't matter.

I'd think in the longer term you'd probably want to treat them as [two aspects of the same service](https://arnon.me/2017/03/services-aspects/) as they'd probably have different update cycle (e.g. the gateway part may need things like auth, maybe additional api in gRPC, etc.),different security reqs (one can accessible to the outside where the other consumes internal resource) different scalability concerns (you'd probably need more resources for the processing) etc.